# Power bank with two USB Type C ports?

Tags: power-bank

Are there power banks with two USB type C ports?
Preferably 20,000 mAH capacity, but 10,000 mAH would also be fine.

I don't care about USB type A or micro USB ports.

Comment: It seems like Samsung just listed some powerbank with 2 type c ports and 10000mAh - https://www.samsung.com/in/smartphones/galaxy-s20/accessories/ . Don't know exact morel name and can't find in shops yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick search, I found these battery devices:

- [XTORM 18W POWER BANK APOLLO 15.000](https://www.xtorm.eu/en/shop/power-banks/xtorm-18w-power-bank-apollo-15-000/)
- [XTORM 45W POWER BANK ROVER 20.000](https://www.xtorm.eu/en/shop/power-banks/xtorm-45w-power-bank-rover-20-000/)
- [XTORM POWER BANK APOLLO 15.000 (LIGHTNING)](https://www.xtorm.eu/en/shop/power-banks/xtorm-power-bank-apollo-15-000-lightning-/)
- [XTORM POWER BANK ROVER 20.000 (LIGHTNING)](https://www.xtorm.eu/en/shop/power-banks/xtorm-power-bank-rover-20-000-lightning-/)
- [AIDEAZ Wireless Power Bank 20000mAh Portable Charger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DWLWLC9)

There are others [mophie powerstation USB-C 3XL Battery](https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/HM8X2ZM/A/mophie-powerstation-usb-c-3xl-battery) with one USB-C as output, and another one as input (in order to charge the PowerBank), I am not sure if that suits you:

Comment: I've spent a lot of time googling and haven't seen those. Thats strange. Thank you